# Swagger generating duplicated model classes

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

Generating server code for [this minimal example](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore-minimal.yaml) using `spring` or `jaxrs-spec` creates 2 model classes: `Pet.java` and `InlineResposne200.java`. Except for the class name, they are identical.

The controller that responds to `/pets` returns a `List<InlineResponse200>` instead of `List<Pet>` and the class `Pet` is actually never used anywhere, even though the yaml definition uses `$ref: "#/definitions/Pet"`. Why is this happening?

```
---
  swagger: "2.0"
  info: 
    version: "1.0.0"
    title: "Swagger Petstore"
    description: "A sample API that uses a petstore as an example to demonstrate features in the swagger-2.0 specification"
    termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
    contact: 
      name: "Swagger API Team"
    license: 
      name: "MIT"
  host: "petstore.swagger.io"
  basePath: "/api"
  schemes: 
    - "http"
  consumes: 
    - "application/json"
  produces: 
    - "application/json"
  paths: 
    /pets: 
      get: 
        description: "Returns all pets from the system that the user has access to"
        produces: 
          - "application/json"
        responses: 
          "200":
            description: "A list of pets."
            schema: 
              type: "array"
              items: 
                $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
  definitions: 
    Pet: 
      type: "object"
      required: 
        - "id"
        - "name"
      properties: 
        id: 
          type: "integer"
          format: "int64"
        name: 
          type: "string"
        tag: 
          type: "string"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried replicating this with `swagger-codegen v2.2.2` using both `spring` and `jaxrs-spec`, but I was not able to get the `InlineResponse200.java`.

However, having done some more digging, I have found that this issue was recently [reported](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1319) as a bug. It has not yet been fixed, but the `InlineResponse200.java` isn't meant to be there.

This file seems to be incorrectly generated when using [`Swagger Editor v3`](http://editor.swagger.io). I'm guessing that's how you generated your file?

Whilst [`Swagger Editor v2`](http://editor2.swagger.io/#!/) does not have this problem, my suggestion for the time being for you would be to install and use the latest stable version of [`swagger-codegen`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate your code from your `Swagger.yaml` file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: generating from my machine using the v2.2.2 worked fine, thanks! I was using the one at `http://editor.swagger.io`

Comment: what are these 'inlineresponse' files?  I cannot find any documenation on them.